# iAd on multiple view controllers

Tags: xcode, iad

I have used iAd's before but only for apps with a single view controller. But I cannot seem to figure out how to create a global reference to the ad in the AppDelegate and fetch it from there for my separate view controllers (That's what I've read I'm supposed to do).

I've been searching for a tutorial on the matter, but for some reason I can't find anything relevant.

Any hints? Point me in the right direction? :)

TIA!
/Markus

Answer (score 1):

In applications there is a adddelegate.h and .m file. You add iad in delegate.m file and create reference in other view : 
in Appdelegate.h add delegate :

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder

ADBannerView *bannerView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *bannerView;

in Appdelegate.m :

@synthesize bannerView;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,nil];
    bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    bannerView.delegate = self;

}

Now you create reference of Appdelegate in other class viewdidload :

AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]delegate];

```
UIView banner = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 32)];
[banner addSubview:appdelegate.bannerView];
[self.view addSubview: banner];
```